# Are account holders with a bank better able to receive a loan from that bank?

Tags: united-states, loans, bank-account

Suppose there is a bank and two people want to get a loan from this bank. They are identical except for that one holds a checking account with the bank and the other doesn't. Will the person holding a checking account be more likely to be approved for the loan or if both are approved will he/she be more likely to get the loan at a lower interest than the other person?

What I'm asking is whether banks in the United States are able and allowed to discriminate (i.e.  treat differently) account holders and account non-holders when making loans?

Comment: Yea sure, and it could work against you.  A person that bounces a lot of checks might be less likely to get a loan than a new customer with similar credit ratings.

Comment: This is going to depend on the policies of the bank.  It's usually more about reducing fees if you have XYZ combination of accounts and/or balances.

Comment: I doubt it. I am a customer with two large banks, and both times when I searched for a mortgage, they declined me and I got it from other banks (and I have credit scores above 800).

Answer (score 0):

Banks are businesses, and as such should have the right to refuse service, so they should probably be able to choose one customer over another at will.

[*I say "should" because business owners protecting themselves against litigation related to discrimination could restrict their freedom as business owners.*]

However, banks are businesses and if the customers are identical, both will be approved (or not) according to credit records.  Does not make sense to approve one person with a given credit record and refuse someone with a similar record.  Unless they barely qualify.  Since no two credit histories are identical, there are surely edge cases.

Finally, if a customer is a long term customer with large deposits and/or significant amounts of business with the bank, the bankers will likely be inclined to do more business.